# Non-constant storage size for autoconf check involving floats?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, autotools, autoconf

I'm working with some autoconf stuff, and there is a test that includes the following:

```
static int test_array [1 - 2 * !((((float)((int)((float)1.4))) == ((float)1.4)) >= 0)];
```

This fails with:

> error: storage size of ‘test_array’ isn’t constant

but when I change this to:

```
static int test_array [1 - 2 * !((((int)((int)((int)1.4))) == ((int)1.4)) >= 0)];
```

it works fine.

I'm not very familiar with all the hacks the autotools employ, but both of these seem like the value should be determinible at compile-time to me.

Why does the first one fail?

Comment: Apparently the second version can be resolved to a constant at compile time, but the first cannot.

Comment: @VladLazarenko updated to make that more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us look at the standard (6.6 (6)):

> An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall only have operands
>   that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof`
>   expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating
>   constants that are the immediate operands of casts. **Cast operators in an integer constant
>   expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types**, except as part of an
>   operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

(emphasis mine).

You must not cast to `float` in an integer constant expression (except in arguments to `sizeof` or `_Alignof`), thus

```
1 - 2 * !((((float)((int)((float)1.4))) == ((float)1.4)) >= 0)
```

isn't an integer constant expression.

The number of elements of a `static` array must be an integer constant expression evaluating to a positive integer.